# How do I remove Spaces from nested list created with for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have created a nested list using for loop. I used the following code:
'''

```
a=[]
for i in range(1,5+1):
        a=a+[[1]*i]
print(a)
```

'''

And the output is:
[image]

How do I remove these spaces before every 1 from the list? I need my list to be modified!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output that you are getting is the default output of python. In order to change it, you can do the following, as mentioned by Prune:

```py
a = []
for i in range (1, 6):
    a += str([1]*i).replace(' ', '')
print(a)

#or

a = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    a += [[1]*i]
a = str(a).replace(' ', '')
print(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

The spaces are part of the default `__repr__` (visual representation) of the list object.
To remove the spaces, you'll have to do your own output processing.

Convert the list to a string.  Remove the spaces from that.  Print:

```
print( str(a).replace(' ', '') )
```

Output:

```
'[[1],[1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]'
```

---

"But how can I make that change in my list?"

You can't.  As I said, those spaces come from `__repr__`, which is called implicitly when you print the list.  There are no spaces in your list, only in the print representation.  You cannot remove the spaces from your in-memory list, any more than you could remove the commas or the brackets.

Comment: I understand your solution. But how can I make that change in my list?

Comment: Your list doesn't have spaces, only the string representation of it! Every element of the lists is the number `1` without any space.

Comment: In a certain sense, you can "make that change in your list", if you make it an instance of your own custom subclass of `list` in which you have overridden `__repr__`.  For example `class MyList(list): __repr__ = lambda self: list.__repr__(self).replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`a=[] for i in range(1,5+1): a=a+[[1]*i] print(a, end='')`?

Comment: I understand your solution. But how can I make that change in my list?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe, by using replace() function?

Comment: Also, if I do not mistake, lower() function deletes spaces as well